# JavaScript - draw on canvas while in while in `requestAnimFrame()`

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to draw on a canvas while in an `requestAnimFrame()` (for a seperate canvas)and all my attempts have failed. I need to be able to access the values from the `canvasFuntion()` in real time while inside of the function containing the  `requestAnimFrame(drawLoop)`. Here is the code:

**(to be clear, `requestAnimFrame()` is identical to `requestAnimationFrame()`)**

```
function canvasFunction(){
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var v = document.getElementById('v');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 100);
    var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight / 100);
    canvas.width = cw;
    canvas.height = ch;

    v.addEventListener('play', function(){
        draw(this,context,cw,ch);
    },false);

},false);

function draw(v,c,w,h) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
    setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
}
}

function drawLoop() {
                    requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
                    //attempting to access values from canvasFunction() 
                    //while inside of this loop
                    canvasFunction(); // does not work (/draw)
                }
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been attempting to solve this problem for a couple days now.

Comment: So exactly why are you adding 60 event listeners per second?

Comment: I just saw you you commented and removed the event listeners, up and running now! Thank you! , if you'd like post without listeners as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the event listeners inside of the `canvasFunction`.

```
function canvasFunction(){
        var v = document.getElementById('v');
        var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth / 100);
        var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight / 100);
        canvas.width = cw;
        canvas.height = ch;
        draw(this,context,cw,ch);

    function draw(v,c,w,h) {
        if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
        c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);
        setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h);
    }
}

function drawLoop() {
    requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
    requestAnimFrame(canvasFunction);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have figured it out yourself :)